# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder" on path

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm having a problem using `Retrofit2` on my AAR module this is the error log:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lretrofit2/Retrofit$Builder;
    at ph.com.jti.ticketko_module.API.RetroFit.Client.getClient(Client.java:19)
    at ph.com.jti.ticketko_module.API.RetroFit.ActivationResponseV2Retrofit.getResponse(ActivationResponseV2Retrofit.java:27)
```

But I'm sure that I have an `multiDexEnabled true` on my app's gradle and on the aar itself. I tried to read [this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1604) regarding on this error and they said that it only needs an **Invalidate cache/restart** but it didn't work. This is the code:

```
import com.androidnetworking.interceptors.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class Client {

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(String baseURL) {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();


    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseURL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();

    return retrofit;
  }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface APIInterface {

@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json", "Project: VElDS0VUS08="})
@POST("/our-end-point")
Call<Data> getActivationDetails(@Body JSONObject jsonObject);
```

}

and this is the main class :

```
 public static synchronized String getResponse(String baseUrl, JSONObject jsonObjectBody) {
    final String[] result = {""};
    String api = "";

    if (baseUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("LOCAL")) {
        api = Environments.getMarkLocalAPI();
    } else if (baseUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("DEVELOPMENT")) {
        api = Environments.getDevelopmentAPI();
    } else if (baseUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("STAGING")) {
        api = Environments.getStagingAPI();
    } else if (baseUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("DEPLOYMENT")) {
        api = Environments.getDeploymentAPI();
    }

    APIInterface apiInterface = Client.getClient(api).create(APIInterface.class);

    Call<Data> call = apiInterface.getActivationDetails(jsonObjectBody);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Data>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Data> call, Response<Data> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                result[0] = String.valueOf(response.body());
            } else {
                result[0] = "no data";
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Data> call, Throwable t) {
            result[0] = t.getMessage();
        }
    });
    return result[0];
}
```

}